# How I find the line equation of Altitude in this triangle with vectors?

Tags: vectors

I have 3 dots of a triangle  : a = (2,5), b = (6,-3), c = (-2,2)
What are the equations of the Altitudes . In other words how do I find the perpendicular vector?

ac = [2--2,5-2]=[4,3];
so the perpendicular vector to ac is [-3,4] and the equation line (theAltitude from b to ac ) is :
x = 6 -3t
y = -3 +4t

is that correct?

Comment: You mean the vector perpendicular to the plane defined by these three points?

Comment: yes,I meant how I find the line equation of the Altitude from b to ac?

Answer (score 1):

First you want to find the general form of a point $d$ that lies on the altitude. Because the vector from $b$ to $d$ is perpendicular to the vector from $a$ to $c$, you can state:

$\vec{bd} \cdot \vec{ac} = 0$

Letting $d = x\mathrm i + y\mathrm j$, you get:$-4(x-6) - 3(y+3) = 0$

Set $x = 0$ to find one such point $d = (0,5)$.

In this case, $\vec {bd} = -6\mathrm i + 8 \mathrm j$, giving the equation:

$$\vec r = 6\mathrm i - 3\mathrm j + \lambda (-6\mathrm i + 8 \mathrm j)$$

which can also be parametrised $x = 6 -6\lambda, y = -3 + 8\lambda$.